# Are salesforce record ids generated lexicographically ?

Tags: salesforce-id, record

I am planning to store the records in a particular object in an HBase table. I want to know if a new record Id is created lexicographically.

Comment: Answered here:  [Are SObject Id's sequential...?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23510/are-sobject-ids-sequential-should-they-be-used-for-defining-batches-in-a-larg) (in a word: No)

Comment: Finally! someone used the "salesforce-id" tag correctly!

Answer (score 1):

the salesforce ids are not generated sequentially. But there is prefix format used for generating an id.

the first 3 digits - unique for object
example : for accounts, all record ids start with 001
          for cases, all record ids start with 005
the next 2 digits - obtained from the Server id (for na1 - D0)

if you are looking at 15 digit ids, then there can be 2 records which have same character sequence but differ only in the case.